# iPhone Facebook 'like' button

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-like

In iPhone software I want to determine if user like facebook page, then some features will make active.
I found this:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
but it makes iFrame and I put it in my webView, but if user liked it this features must be active on every device he or she got.

It is posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately if you put this in a normal `UIWebView` it will not work as intended. A user's cookies from other apps and Mobile Safari are not included when a `UIWebView` requests a URL. This means that Facebook has no way of authenticating the user to determine if they have *liked* an object in the Social Graph.

I recommend that you that a look at Facebook's SDK for iOS. https://developers.facebook.com/ios/
They will offer some means of checking a user's *likes*. It will deal with user authentication and is relatively easy to get started with.

Hope this helps!